# Why does my keyboard get dismissed at each keystroke when I extract a View with a TextInput to a function, but not when I return it directly?

Tags: react-native

I created a FormInput component which encapsulates a View with a TextInput:

```
<FormInput inputType="text" title={translate("Exam Name")} value={name} setValue={setName} ref={examNameRef} required />
```

Inside FormInput I do the following:

```
if (inputType === 'text') {
// return (
//   <View style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} >
//     <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
//       <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
//       {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
//     </View>
//     <View>
//       {requiredValidationError ?
//         <Text style={[styles.fieldValue, { borderColor: 'red', color: 'red' }]}>{'Campo Obrigatório'}</Text>
//         :
//         <TextInput style={[styles.fieldValue]} value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />
//       }
//     </View>
//   </View>
// )
return <InputText />
```

The function InputText has the same code as the commented code above:

```
   function InputText() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
          {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
        </View>
        <View>
          {requiredValidationError ?
            <Text style={[styles.fieldValue, { borderColor: 'red', color: 'red' }]}>{'Campo Obrigatório'}</Text>
            :
            <TextInput style={[styles.fieldValue]} value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

When I use it like this my keyboard keeps getting dismissed at every key stroke,but when I uncomment the commented part above and return the View directly instead of putting it inside a function this bug doesn't happen. What could be the problem?

Here's the whoe FormInput.js:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Text, Pressable, View, TextInput, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Platform, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation, useRoute, useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { translate } from '../../translate';
import Page from '../../components/Page';
import Picker from '../../components/Picker';
import Modal from '../../components/Modal';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

import moment from 'moment';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
Icon.loadFont();

const FormInput = forwardRef(({ inputType, title, value, setValue, required, maxLength }, ref) => {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value);
  const [dateTimePickerMode, setDateTimePickerMode] = useState("date");
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [requiredValidationError, setRequiredValidationError] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    validate() {
      if (required) {
        if (internalValue) {
          setRequiredValidationError(false)
        } else {
          setRequiredValidationError(true)
        }
      }
    },
    error: requiredValidationError
  }));

  const onChangeDate = (event, newDate) => {
    if (event.type === "dismissed") {
      setDateTimePickerMode("date")
      setModalVisible(false);
      return;
    }
    const dateWithTime = new Date(date);
    if (dateTimePickerMode === 'date') {
      setModalVisible(true);
      setDate(newDate || new Date());
      setDateTimePickerMode('time');
    } else {
      setModalVisible(false);
      dateWithTime.setHours(newDate.getHours());
      dateWithTime.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes());
      setDateTimePickerMode('date');
      setValue(dateWithTime);
    }
  }

  function InputSwitch() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.button, { paddingRight: 15 }]} >
        <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>{title}</Text>
        <View style={{ marginRight: 30 }}>
          <Switch
            style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: Platform.select({ ios: 0.8, android: 1.3 }) }, { scaleY: Platform.select({ ios: 0.8, android: 1.3 }) }] }}
            thumbColor={"#f4f3f4"}
            onValueChange={setValue}
            value={value}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  function InputText() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
          {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
        </View>
        <View>
          {requiredValidationError ?
            <Text style={[styles.fieldValue, { borderColor: 'red', color: 'red' }]}>{'Campo Obrigatório'}</Text>
            :
            <TextInput style={[styles.fieldValue]} value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  function InputNumber() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
          {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={[styles.fieldValue, { borderColor: requiredValidationError ? 'red' : 'grey', color: requiredValidationError ? 'red' : 'grey' }]}>{requiredValidationError ? 'Campo Obrigatório' : value}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  function InputDate() {
    return (
      <View>
        {inputType === 'date' && modalVisible && (
          <DateTimePicker
            testID="dateTimePicker"
            value={internalValue ? new Date(internalValue) : new Date()}
            is24Hour={true}
            mode={dateTimePickerMode}
            onChange={onChangeDate}
          />
        )}
        <Pressable style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)} >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
            {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.fieldValue}>{value ? moment(value).format('DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm') : ''}</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    )
  }


  if (inputType === 'text') {
    // return (
    //   <View style={[styles.button, { height: 90 }]} >
    //     <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    //       <Text style={[styles.fieldLabel, {}]}>{title}</Text>
    //       {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{' *'}</Text>}
    //     </View>
    //     <View>
    //       {requiredValidationError ?
    //         <Text style={[styles.fieldValue, { borderColor: 'red', color: 'red' }]}>{'Campo Obrigatório'}</Text>
    //         :
    //         <TextInput style={[styles.fieldValue]} value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />
    //       }
    //     </View>
    //   </View>
    // )
    return <InputText />
  } else if (inputType === 'number') {
    return <InputNumber />
  } else if (inputType === 'switch') {
    return <InputSwitch />
  } else if (inputType === 'date') {
    return <InputDate />
  } else {
    return <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', textAlign: 'center', padding: 10, margin: 10 }}>Input do tipo {inputType} não está implementado</Text>
  }

})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#A7A6A6',
    marginBottom: 100
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#FF000010',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: Platform.select({ ios: 10, android: 10 })
  },
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 32,
    color: '#626262',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#00FF0010',
  },
  modalView: {
    marginVertical: 230,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  button: {
    padding: 5
  },
  fieldLabel: {
    color: "grey",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  fieldValue: {
    color: "black",
    textAlign: "right",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    textAlign: 'right',
    borderColor: 'grey',
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 4,
    color: '#626262',
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#626262',
    width: 300,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
});

export default FormInput;
```

And the return of the parent component:

```
    return (
    <>
        <Page type="static" title={'Avaliação'} subtitle={'Editar'}>
            <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0.8, paddingHorizontal: 5}} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                <FormInput inputType="text" title={translate("Exam Name")} value={name} setValue={setName} ref={examNameRef} required />
                <FormInput inputType="text" title={translate("Code")} value={code} setValue={setCode} maxLength={8} ref={examCodeRef} required />
                <FormInput inputType="number" title={translate("Max Grade")} value={maxGrade} setValue={setMaxGrade} />
                <FormInput inputType="number" title={translate("Weight")} value={weight} setValue={setWeight} ref={examWeightRef} required />
                <FormInput inputType="date" title={translate("Start Date")} value={startDate} setValue={setStartDate} />
                <FormInput inputType="date" title={translate("End Date")} value={endDate} setValue={setEndDate} />
                <FormInput inputType="switch" title={translate("Ignore Formula")} value={ignoreFormula} setValue={setIgnoreFormula} />
            </ScrollView>
        </Page>
        <View style={{}}>
            <Button style={[styles.button, {}]} textStyle={styles.buttonText} title={translate('Save')} onPress={() => saveExam()} requestFeedback />
        </View>
    </>
);
```

Comment: Maybe  you are not passing ``value`` and ``setValue`` to the ``InputText`` component properly. Can you show us where these state are declared?

Comment: I edited including the whole file